# ¿por que mi petición post a una api no se ejecuta?

Tags: json, vba, tokens

Estoy intentando enviar una petición post a la api de mercado libre para crear las tiendas,
mi problema es que cuando ejecuto el request de la petición post este se salta el paso desde visual studio sin ejecutarse el código.
La solicitud que estoy ejecutando es con un token y archivo Json que se envian a la solitud de la api en donde trato de hacer

Archivo Json que se genera para la solicitud

```
 {
 "name":"CASA MATRZ",
 "business_hours":{
  "monday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  },
  "tuesday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  },
  "wednesday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  },
  "thursday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  },
  "friday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  },
  "saturday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  },
  "sunday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  }
 },
 "location":{
  "street_number":"0",
  "street_name":"AMERICO VESPUCIO 2700",
  "city_name":"SANTIAGO",
  "state_name":"SANTIAGO",
  "latitude":-74.05306,
  "longitude":4.667034,
  "reference":"1234"
 },
 "external_id":"191-99-NB-TI-FN"
 }
```

El código que tengo para hacer la petición a la api haciendo el post

```
   Public Async Function SendJsonWithTokenAsync(ByVal tokens, ByVal data, ByVal respuesta, ByVal ruta) As Task

    Dim url As String = ruta
    Dim token As String = tokens


    Using client As New HttpClient()
        ' Configurar el token de autenticación
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token)

        ' Crear el contenido HTTP con el archivo JSON
        Dim content As New MultipartFormDataContent()
        content.Add(New StringContent(data, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "jsonFile", "data.json")

        ' Realizar la solicitud POST
        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync(url, content)

        ' Leer la respuesta
        Dim responseContent As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

        ' Manejar la respuesta como desees
        Console.WriteLine("Respuesta: " + responseContent)
    End Using
End Function
```